# Android does not support database driver for Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL Server

Tags: android, database

I want to connect to a MySQL server database from an android client. I read that using a Web Service between them is one of the best approach.

I also read that it is not possible(or it should be really hard) to connect directly to a database(MySql server, MS SQL server and Oracle) from Android because the database drivers are not supported by android. Is it right?

I appreciate for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you are going to get to something "official" is the fact that these databases are not listed under data storage options in the official list [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Of course, nothing is preventing support for these databases later. You may even find libraries to do this at unofficial sources.

### EDIT

If you wish, you can research using JDBC to connect to these databases. Here is an SO question regarding that. [JDBC connection in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447692/jdbc-connection-in-android)

Comment: i think he means a distant database.

Comment: I see, my answer isn't geared towards the web services option (which would be possible). If there is some propiertary format that you need to speak to "connect directly" to a distant database, there is no native/official support for this. You will need another library. You might want to look into JDBC on Android.

Comment: Hi, yes maybe you are right. The second part of my question in not right about database drivers in Android. JDBC is the approach that let us to connect to that databases without Web Service. Can you take o look on this post and help me regarding that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318614/benefits-of-web-service-between-a-smart-phone-client-and-database