# Facebook SDK for Android: Trying to get a notification when one "likes/comment" the post made by my Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I'm fairly new to Facebook SFD for Android.

What I'm trying to achieve is an Android app that uses facebook login, post to the user timeline and gets notified whenever one is commenting or liking that post.

I went thru Facebook tutorials for login and for Publish to Feed.
All went well.

Now I'm struggling with the last part. I don't see how to be notified whenever there is a like or comments. I browsed the web and stackoverflow forum without any success. I'm guessing that there is a mechanism to be notified by Facebook and that I don't have to start a process just to monitor the post...
Anyone could give me a hint on the API to use?

I'm currently looking at "Creating Object Types" section Associating Actions with Object Creation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-object-types) but it looks like this describes how to do for facebook web app, and not for android app.

EDIT

I've found this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/ but not quite sure how to "translate" this into Android coding.
If anyone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to create a page in php that will handle the responses from Facebook, it starts with a

- `GET` response from Facebook that you retrieve with `$_GET["name"]` in php, and you have to send back a confirmation to Facebook to confirm that the connection works, and Facebook will send you the answer you want via
- a POST request ( `$_POST["name"]` ) (with a json object, containing the informations about the user in `object` for example, and the different updates in `entry`).

You can put all these informations in a database, and when the user start your application, you can automatically connect him to a php script that check if the database has new informations for him.

(specifying who he is, with a `user` variable that he keeps in the memory of his device, and then you ask for informations from the database about this `user`). I haven't tested, but it should work.

Comment: I understand the way you see it however, I think it is overkill to create a page that will handle this since all I want is the user to be notified while he's using the app. You can see this as a user who would start reading a book, so as he starts to read my app is posting on Facebook. While he's reading, my app gets notified of FB friends liking or commenting on the post stating that the user started his book.

Comment: About webservices, you can read this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136636/connecting-mysql-with-android-without-using-php . Using a php page is the common way to communicate with a remote server, with what is outside your application. To avoid a database, you can just add a playerpreference to store the user ID and when needed, you send this ID to the php page, that will handle the connection with Facebook.