# How to connect MYSQL DataBase from android application without php script?

Tags: android

How to connect MYSQL DataBase from  android application without php script ?

I was tried  using JDBC CONNECTOR . But unable to build the project  . Can anyone tell me  , what is the best steps for to connect MYSQL Database from android application .

Comment: You can read on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136636/connecting-mysql-with-android-without-using-php/

Answer (score 4):

web service is simply some code on the internet (web) which allows you to receive and send information to a server, where it is saved per example in a database.

PHP is just a language, in which you can write a web service.

You can use array of languages to create a web service ( read: expose your database) to other devices. Among others, you can easily do this in Java, .NET, Python ...

If you're looking for a way to connect to an external database without any web service / API in between, i'll have to disappoint you with the news that this is not supported by Android.

Most examples of a simple web service / a bunch of scripts contain PHP since this is probably the easiest and can be used on pretty much any server.

Answer (score -1):

This should help. How to connect Android with PHP to MySQL

http://berthojoris.com/menu/blog/artikel/How-to-connect-Android-with-PHP-MySQL.aspx