# Android login while working with mobile phone but working fine in emulator

Tags: android

I developed android app using this website.
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/22/create-simple-login-form-php-android-connect-php-android/

but i am able to login in emulator but when i am trying in my mobile it is not showing anythings. how to over come that.

Comment: You are probably running the PHP server locally, hence why the phone won't find it. Also, please try to rephrase a bit your question or share your code, that always. helps.

Comment: show your logcat then we can help you.

Comment: More info please, code at least.

Comment: same as above code i have done.please check that url kindly.

Comment: give your ip address of device where you hosted your server.. httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php"); check this line and give your ip address over here and try

Comment: i have changed with my system ip address no problem with that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. The problem might be due to Certificate signing at the time of connection or proxy settings or maybe IP or maybe something like KNOX agent that might stop connection. I started using jdbc and it worked for me. It is easier than php. This might help you [JDBC connection in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447692/jdbc-connection-in-android).