# AsyncTask Errors

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I was originally doing interfacing directly in my UI and was receiving errors. I changed to using an AsyncTask instead of the previous configuration and I am now receiving different errors errors. I'm not sure why it is throwing the errors.

LightsMainScreen.java

```
package com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightTest1;

public class LightsMainScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lights_main);

        Button returnBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.returnBtn);
        ToggleButton light3Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_3);

        light3Btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                new UpdateXML().execute();  }   }   )   ;

        returnBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();   }   }   )   ;
    }

    private class UpdateXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        ToggleButton light3Btn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light_3);

        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(light3Btn.isChecked()) LightTest1.XMLUpdate("1", "3", "1");
            else LightTest1.XMLUpdate("1", "3", "0");
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute()  {}

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        protected void onProgressUpdate()   {}
    }
}
```

LightTest1.java

```
package com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import com.lnrpuc.Services.GetNamesRequestType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.GetNamesResponseType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.GetStatusRequestType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.GetStatusResponseType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.SetStatusRequestType;
import com.lnrpuc.Services.SetStatusResponseType;


public class LightTest1 {

    public static void XMLUpdate(String object, String number, String status){
        try {
            HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy proxy = new HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy();

            //names request
            //GetNamesRequestType inGNRT = new GetNamesRequestType();
            //inGNRT.setPass("12345");

            //GetNamesResponseType outGNRT = proxy.getNames(inGNRT);
            //System.out.println(outGNRT.get_return());

            //status request
            //GetStatusRequestType inGSRT = new GetStatusRequestType();
            //inGSRT.setPass("12345");

            //GetStatusResponseType outGSRT = proxy.getStatus(inGSRT);
            //System.out.println(outGSRT.get_return());

            //set status
            SetStatusRequestType inSSRT = new SetStatusRequestType();
            inSSRT.setPass("12345");
            inSSRT.setObject(object);
            inSSRT.setNumber(number);
            inSSRT.setStatus(status);

            SetStatusResponseType outSSRT = proxy.setStatus(inSSRT);
            System.out.println(outSSRT.get_return());


        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("failed");
        }


    }
}
```

LogCat Output

```
02-06 13:53:38.759: I/dalvikvm(16012): Failed resolving Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortType; interface 93 'Ljava/rmi/Remote;'
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): Link of class 'Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortType;' failed
02-06 13:53:38.759: I/dalvikvm(16012): Failed resolving Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy; interface 30 'Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortType;'
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): Link of class 'Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy;' failed
02-06 13:53:38.759: E/dalvikvm(16012): Could not find class 'com.lnrpuc.Services.HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy', referenced from method com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightTest1.XMLUpdate
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 31 (Lcom/lnrpuc/Services/HomeAutomationServicePortTypeProxy;) in Lcom/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1;
02-06 13:53:38.759: D/dalvikvm(16012): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 94 (Ljava/rmi/RemoteException;)
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x26
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY:  rejected Lcom/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1;.XMLUpdate (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
02-06 13:53:38.759: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0026
02-06 13:53:38.769: W/dalvikvm(16012): VFY:  rejected Lcom/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1;.XMLUpdate (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
02-06 13:53:38.769: W/dalvikvm(16012): Verifier rejected class Lcom/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1;
02-06 13:53:38.769: W/dalvikvm(16012): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417c0898)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/lnrpuc/lnrpucseniordesign/LightTest1
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightsMainScreen$UpdateXML.doInBackground(LightsMainScreen.java:41)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at com.lnrpuc.lnrpucseniordesign.LightsMainScreen$UpdateXML.doInBackground(LightsMainScreen.java:1)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-06 13:53:38.769: E/AndroidRuntime(16012):    ... 3 more
```

Comment: [Maybe this post will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105578/java-lang-verifyerror)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot use UI elements off the main thread (e.g. in an AsyncTask). I suggest you get rid of the AsyncTask and try to solve the original errors.

Comment: @BarryFruitman sure you can! That's why that class has 4 methods. `doInBackground()` can't update the `UI Thread` but any of the other 3 can and is why they exist.

Comment: Well the problem with the original layout was trying to do networking in the UI. What if I do the UI work in the main thread and then send values to the AsyncTask?

Comment: @JustinLasecki I don't see anything you are doing wrong as far as the `UI` and `AsyncTask`. If you were updating the `UI` then you would get a different exception. Something along the lines of `Only the original thread that created the view can update it`. It looks like its an issue with a library you are using.

Comment: [Here are the docs for that error](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/VerifyError.html) not real helpful to solve. [And here are the Java docs for it](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Flang%2FVerifyError.html&ei=v-_zUrH_G6GMyQG91IH4Aw&usg=AFQjCNFkcIbN14m1-D1_Y1jjcbrEBLexPg&sig2=nBZ79zKSA7UiGYWzeotA8A&bvm=bv.60983673,d.aWc)